# Is it possible to program an Android app that changes the font opacity in other apps? (e.x. Telegram or whatsapp)

Tags: android, text, fonts, telegram, opacity

So the question is, is it possible to change the font opacity in specific apps like Telegram or WhatsApp with a self-developed app? I don't need to get any personal data related to privacy, just changing the design of the interface.

If yes, which direction to look into? I don't have any background in programming android app, but would be really glad if there are some reference tutorials or android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible. Of course, the operating system can do some UI changes, for example, if you are using contrast or dark mode or some other accessibility feature. But there is no way you can directly change the opacity of a specific application that you don't own the code to.